# How do I add custom properties to dependency tracking?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I have an operation with many SQL dependencies. Right now, prior to any such dependency I log some key parameters to describe the operation eg:

```
_log.LogInformation("Fetching document with Id {Id}", id);
_db.FetchById(id);
```

This (obviously) shows up as two separate entries in app insights console, and the information doesn't show up inlined in the timeline view, which makes it a bit harder to trace flows.

Is it possible to add some scope variables prior to calling the dependency such that they'll appear in the dependency's properties?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? I'm not very clear your issue:(

Comment: Are we talking about .Net full framework or .Net Core?

Comment: If you want to enrich the dependency telemetry with additional properties, then you can write telemetry initializers to store id or anything else into DependencyTelemetry as custom properties.